# Google Play Store Key

Tags: visual-studio-2015, google-play, android-keystore

I Create Xamarine forms App (android && iOS)
I Publish Android APK On Google Play Store using Key Store && certificate (which imported in visual studio).
I have to change operating system and i miss key store
now i want to upload new Release,
How Can I Retrieve Key Store,
Or How Can I Upload New APk AND Update Existing One.
Thank You

Answer (score 2):

If you lose your keystore and don't have backup you can't update your existing app anymore.

You need to generate a new keystore and change the package name to reupload it, if you try to reupload the app to Google Play with same package name it gona get refused.

Finally you need inform the current users of old keystore for swap to the new package to continue getting updates, tag the old upload as [Deprecated],  explain the problem and include the link of new package on old package info into developer console.